# Back-to-back but less colloquial

Tags: word-request

What is the word to say that something is located so close to something different, that there is no real distance between them?

**Example 1:** Three houses that are built with no physical distance between them. You know they are different houses and not the single one just because they are built in different styles.

**Example 2:** Two cars that are parked at a distance of one centimeter.

Google Translate suggest *back-to-back*, but:

1. It sounds colloquial, and I suspect that there are more formal ways to say it.
2. When I hear *back-to-back*, I think about something like a scene from Conan The Barbarian movies: there are two warriors who are fighting back-to-back against dozens of bad guys, and of course, win. In other words, *back-to-back* sounds wrong when we talk about more than two items.

Comment: 'Back to back' is not really colloquial. Also, it doesn't mean 'close', it means 'facing in opposite directions'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks, this is important. But what is the word to describe the examples above?

Comment: For houses, you would say "attached". For the cars, you'd say "touching" (if they were in contact with each other) or "nearly touching" (if they were a centimeter apart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Houses that are side by side with no distance at all, and may share walls, are often called terraced houses (UK) or 'row houses' (USA).

[image]

Two cars that are parked close together are 'close together'; there may be other things you can say about them, e.g. facing the same way, back to back, etc.

More than two items can be 'back to back'.

This is a picture of 'back to back' terraced houses:

[image]

If two things are very close, they are *adjacent*. If there no distance between them, so that they touch, they are *immediately adjacent*; they *abut each other*; they are *touching*; they are *in contact*.

Comment: In other words, "close to" assumes less distance than "near to", but there is no word to describe the "so close that there is no real or even physical distance or space between A and B" case? (In Russian, we use the word "вплотную" for this.)

Comment: If two things are very close, they are _adjacent_. If there no distance between them, so that they touch, they are _immediately adjacent_; they _abut_ each other; they are _touching_; they are _in contact_.

Answer (score 1):

[Back-to-back](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/back-to-back) in AmE means *happening one after another, without interruption*, so it means close in time, not in physical position. "I've got back-to-back meetings today, so I won't have time for lunch."

In the UK, [a specific type of terraced house](https://everipedia.org/wiki/lang_en/Back-to-back_house) that share walls with other houses is referred to as a "back-to-back". In AmE, it can also refer to two things positioned with their backs close together or touching, but it doesn't have the general sense of "very close together".

For physical closeness, a similar phrase would be "[packed together](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/packed+together)" if there were many things in a small area. It is usually used when the area is confined, for example, *The employees were packed together in the small conference room because the larger room was being renovated.*

You could also say "[crowded together](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/crowded+together)" (*To position things close together. In this usage, a noun or pronoun can be used between "crowd" and "together."* :

> I tried **crowding** all of my clothes **together** to make room for my jacket, but it still wouldn't fit in the suitcase.

> Because the tall tombs resemble small houses **crowded together**, the cemeteries of New Orleans are often referred to as “cities of the dead.” ([Source](https://64parishes.org/entry/st-louis-cemetery-no-1-no-2-and-no-3))

Comment: In the UK it is used for a specific physical situation of back-to-back houses which, I hope, we no longer build now. So we might use it for physical proximity although not commonly.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks - I've incorporated that... I meant that in terms of describing things that are very close together, back-to-back is temporal. I think that is different than describing things that are positioned with their backs close together or touching.  I don't think houses that shared only their side walls and had a back garden would be called back-to-backs, or would they?

Comment: No - it says not in the link you provided.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, sometimes the way people use words isn't as limited as the way a writer has defined the term for an article.